# Inverse of covariant tensor of rank two is contravariant.

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm studying tensors on my own, using "Tensor Calculus" from David C. Kay, and there is this theorem in page $29$:

> Suppose that $(T_{ij})$ is a covariant tensor of order two. If the matrix $[T_{ij}]_{nn}$ is invertible on $\scr U$, with inverse matrix $[T^{ij}]_{nn},$ then $(T^{ij})$ is a contravariant tensor or order two.

Here, $\scr U$ is only the domain. He gives no proof at the moment (and I don't know if he will later), but I want to take a shot at this. Basically:

**Have:** $${\overline{T}}_{ij} = T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline{x}}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline{x}}^j}, \qquad T_{ik}T^{kj} = \delta_i^j, \quad T^{ik}T_{kj} = \delta^i_j.$$

**Want:** $${\overline{T}}^{ij} = T^{rs}\frac{\partial {\overline{x}}^i}{\partial x^r}\frac{\partial {\overline{x}}^j}{\partial x^s}$$

Can I also say that ${\overline{T}}_{ik}{\overline{T}}^{kj} = \delta_i^j$? Why?

My only ideas were: $${\overline{T}}_{ij} = T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline{x}}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline{x}}^j} \implies {\overline{T}}^{ki}{\overline{T}}_{ij} = {\overline{T}}^{ki}T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline{x}}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline{x}}^j} \implies {\overline{T}}^{ki}T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline{x}}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline{x}}^j}  = \delta^k_j,$$ but I don't know what to do with this. At least the indices are ok (on a side note, I never know if the correct is "indices" or "indexes", English is not my first language), so this is not entirely nonsense.

And: $$T^{ik}T_{kj}={\overline{T}}^{ik}{\overline{T}}_{kj} \implies T^{ik}T_{kj}={\overline{T}}^{ik}T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline{x}}^k}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline{x}}^j},$$ and maybe cancelling something here, somehow?

Comment: meanwhile I prepare an answer, check: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/plural-of-index-indexes-or-indices , personally I prefer *indexes*

Comment: Thanks! I found this comment interesting there:

>"The plural of the noun index should always be indices. This handily distinguishes it from the present tense of the verb index, which can only be indexes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed say that ${\overline T}_{ik}{\overline T}^{kj}=\delta_i^j$. This is because the definition of $T^{ij}$ is that in *each basis* its components are such that it is the inverse of $T_{jk}$.

Your line of working

$${\overline T}_{ij} = T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline x}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline x}^j} \implies {\overline T}^{ki}{\overline T}_{ij} = {\overline T}^{ki}T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline x}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline x}^j} \implies {\overline T}^{ki}T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline x}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline x}^j}  = \delta^k_j$$

is correct, and in fact you are very nearly done! You just need to use the fact that $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial {\overline x}^j}$ has the inverse $\frac{\partial {\overline x}^j}{\partial x^k}$. We also already know the inverse of $T_{rs}$ is $T^{st}$, so starting with your equation

$${\overline T}^{ki}T_{rs}\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline x}^i}\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline x}^j}  = \delta^k_j$$

try to move everything apart from ${\overline T}^{ki}$ to the right hand side. You should end up with what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your answer was very helpful. I've done it, but how can I justify this step at the end? $$\overline{T}^{ik}\delta^q_r = T^{pr} \frac{\partial \overline{x}^i}{\partial x^p}\frac{\partial \overline{x}^k}{\partial x^q} \implies \overline{T}^{ik} = T^{pq} \frac{\partial \overline{x}^i}{\partial x^p}\frac{\partial \overline{x}^k}{\partial x^q} $$ (I mean, the delta going to the other side)

Comment: @IvoTerek I think you must have made a mistake somewhere. Make sure none of your formulas have the same index in them three time or something. I think you might be trying to multiply both sides by $\frac{\partial {\overline x}^i}{\partial x^p}$ at some point when "$i$" still appears twice on the LHS.

Comment: The terms have to cross over in a particular order. Try writing out the terms so that terms with matching indices are next to each other: ${\overline T}^{ki}\left(\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline x}^i}\right)T_{rs}\left(\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline x}^j}\right)  = \delta^k_j$ Since each term has two indices this is like having four matrices multiplied together: $ABCD=I$.

Comment: In order to leave $A$ on the LHS we have to multiply by $D^{-1}$ then $C^{-1}$ then $B^{-1}$ to get $A=D^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}$. So you have to do $\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial {\overline x}^j}$ then $T_{rs}$ and then $\frac{\partial x^r}{\partial {\overline x}^i}$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought that the order mattered. I'll redo the calculations and give you more feedback in a few minutes, thanks :)